# UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha: occur crash in iOS 17. How to fix that?

Tags: ios, uiimage

The code runs correctly before iOS 17.0. This is the stack message of the crash in iOS 17.0. Is this a new bug in iOS 17.0?

```
0   VideoToolbox                    0x00000001b145025c ___VTDecompressionSessionRemote_DecodeTile_block_invoke_2 :60 (in VideoToolbox)
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a8a8b300 __dispatch_client_callout :20 (in libdispatch.dylib)
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001a8a9a6b4 __dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete :56 (in libdispatch.dylib)
3   VideoToolbox                    0x00000001b14500e0 _VTDecompressionSessionRemote_DecodeTile :696 (in VideoToolbox)
4   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4f9cb70 _VTTileDecompressionPluginClass_decode :376 (in CMPhoto)
5   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4fa2974 __decodeItem :6008 (in CMPhoto)
6   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4f9278c __applyDecodeStrategy :396 (in CMPhoto)
7   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4ff755c __decodeImage :452 (in CMPhoto)
8   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4ff3418 __createImageForIndex :472 (in CMPhoto)
9   CMPhoto                         0x00000001c4fae3b0 _CMPhotoDecompressionContainerCreateImageForIndex :280 (in CMPhoto)
10  ImageIO                         0x00000001a696fe74 __ZN14HEIFReadPlugin20copyImageBlockSetImpEP7InfoRecP15CGImageProvider6CGRect6CGSizePK14__CFDictionary :2208 (in ImageIO)
11  ImageIO                         0x00000001a69722dc __ZN14HEIFReadPlugin14decodeImageImpEP18IIODecodeParameter12IIOImageTypePP11__IOSurfacePP10__CVBufferPP15CGImageBlockSet :616 (in ImageIO)
12  ImageIO                         0x00000001a67dd55c __ZN13IIOReadPlugin15callDecodeImageEP18IIODecodeParameter12IIOImageTypePP11__IOSurfacePP10__CVBufferPP15CGImageBlockSet :800 (in ImageIO)
13  ImageIO                         0x00000001a67dce90 __ZN10IIO_Reader21CopyImageBlockSetProcEPvP15CGImageProvider6CGRect6CGSizePK14__CFDictionary :688 (in ImageIO)
14  ImageIO                         0x00000001a67dcaf8 __ZN20IIOImageProviderInfo28copyImageBlockSetWithOptionsEP15CGImageProvider6CGRect6CGSizePK14__CFDictionary :744 (in ImageIO)
15  ImageIO                         0x00000001a67dc728 __ZN20IIOImageProviderInfo28CopyImageBlockSetWithOptionsEPvP15CGImageProvider6CGRect6CGSizePK14__CFDictionary :804 (in ImageIO)
16  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2726dd8 _imageProvider_retain_data :92 (in CoreGraphics)
17  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2711098 _CGDataProviderRetainData :80 (in CoreGraphics)
18  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a27110e0 _provider_for_destination_retain_data :28 (in CoreGraphics)
19  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2711098 _CGDataProviderRetainData :80 (in CoreGraphics)
20  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2710d64 _CGAccessSessionCreate :124 (in CoreGraphics)
21  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a270dfec _img_data_lock :2400 (in CoreGraphics)
22  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a270d640 _CGSImageDataLock :1324 (in CoreGraphics)
23  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2718a54 _ripc_AcquireRIPImageData :848 (in CoreGraphics)
24  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2718290 _ripc_DrawImage :832 (in CoreGraphics)
25  CoreGraphics                    0x00000001a2717dc8 _CGContextDrawImageWithOptions :1120 (in CoreGraphics)
26  UIKitCore                       0x00000001a2e47b00 -[UIImage drawInRect:blendMode:alpha:] :1072 (in UIKitCore)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: I also got this crash. Any findings?